# Laravel: Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\QueueableCollection' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a console (Artisan) command to run a custom-made package. The import of the package and all of its functions is working just fine, but I can't seem to query any eloquent models without having the following error pop up:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   
Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\QueueableCollection' not found
```

Here is my code...

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Property;
use Sync;

class SyncTool extends Command {

    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'sync:all';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $credentials = [
            ...
        ];

        $sync = new Sync( $credentials );

        $properties = Property::all(); // this throws the error

    }


}
```

Comment: I don't know this can help or no, but can you run `composer install` or `composer update`? this error caused by missing package

Comment: Tried that - didn't seem to work.

Comment: okay then you have to download it directly from the github and put it in directory`vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Contracts/Queue`, you can download it here https://github.com/illuminate/contracts/tree/master/Queue

Comment: While I believe this would have worked, Exprator's solution worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Step 1 : Remove full vendor folder 
Step 2:  delete /bootstrap/cache/services.php, /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php
Step 3 : Run from your terminal composer install
```

try this

Comment: That seemed to fix it! Thanks a ton!

Comment: you are most welcome, dont forget to accept as an answer if it helped